# GC Cloud function Error from file zip: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Setting up a cloud function via zip file with python files. Project is set up as

```
. project_cf
|
main.py
requirements.txt
otherlib.py
more.py
```

When I go to upload the project I receive the following message: `Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist`

`main.py` is called via `main:start`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be resolved by ensuring when zipping the folder you don't actually zip the folder, just the files.

[See the note in deployment documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/console#create_a_function):

> Note: Make sure your source files are at the root of the ZIP file,
>   rather than a folder containing the files.

You can do this via -

1. `cd your_project_directory`
2. `zip -r your_project.zip .` (osx)

This puts all the files into one zip at the root, rather than in a directory down.